# string concatenation with void pointers

Tags: c

I've a generic print function intended to return a string of concatenated output with a void pointer type and some char * type variables.

**Question**

1. Is it possible to print void *
2. If not, then can someone please at least review the code about `malloc` and `strcat`.

**Function**

```
const char * print(char *name, void *data, char *type) {
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(name) + sizeof(data) + sizeof(type)); // do I need + 1 for null?
    strcat(str, name); // name is never NULL
    if (data) strcat(str, data); // data can be NULL
    if (type) strcat(str, type); // type can be NULL
    return str;
}
```

**Usage**

```
struct {int value;} obj = {5};
char *result = print("Test", &obj, "type");
puts(result);
```

Comment: `sizeof` is not `strlen`

Comment: `strcat(str, data)`. What is that intended to do since `data` is not a string?

Comment: If a C question contains the word _"generic "_, the answer is most likely "no". More specifically you can't write a generic print function, because `print` has no way to know what `data` points to. And `strcat` can only be use for strings, passing anything else that a pointer to a string makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: `int n; n = snprintf(0, 0, "what%ev%er", ...); char *res = malloc(n + 1); sprintf(res, "what%ev%er", ...); /* remember to free(res) later */`

Comment: thanks for the comments, do I need +1 at the end? `malloc(strlen(name) + strlen(type));`

Comment: I didn't read it, any reference link please

Comment: I found the answer on a page. Thanks for your help